Translator from xy diagrams to tikz-cd diagrams
I have a paper accepted in a journal which forbids the use of the xy package. I must use the tikz-cd package instead (that I don't even know). Given the number of diagrams in the paper, it means a huge work.
Is there a translator somewhere available doing that ?

Ten years ago, someone asked the same Q156689. The script might still work but will produce legacy input syntax. \arrow[<path options>]{<target>}[<node options>]{<node>} instead of \arrow[<path options>, <target>, "<node>" <node options>] but it should still work.

Instead of translating them, you could create vector graphics with the xy package and include them as graphics.

@Qrrbrbirlbel I have an Ubuntu computer; I'm going to try out the script; hopefully, it will work otherwise it would take me several weeks working only on that; it's crazy really.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz How do I do that please ?

@PhilippeGaucher You could make a copy of your article, change to the standalone class, delete all text between the xy pictures and tell the standalone class to start a new page for each picture. This should give you a pdf with each graph on a separate page which you can then include in your article.

@Qrrbrbirlbel The script does not work. The output file is exactly the input file...

@PhilippeGaucher the script works ok for the example given in the other question (I just tested it). It might not work correctly for more complex diagrams but at least it should output something. Are you sure you call the script in the right way?

@Marijn I have translated all diagrams from xy to tikz-cd by hand...
